# How can I deploy MVC App on IIS 5.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-5

I want to deploy an MVC application on IIS 5.1. I am using MVC 2.
How can I do so? It seems bit difficult?

regards,
Kaps

Comment: What's difficult?  Could you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 6):

You have to add wildcard mapping as follows.

1. Right-click on the virtual directory and choose properties.
2. On the `Virtual Directory` tab, select `Configuration`.
3. On the first tab, hit add.
4. Browse ASP.NET ISAPI.
5. Type `.*` for extension.
6. Uncheck `Check that file exists`.
7. Click ok.

Comment: Hi, when i add extension `.*`, cgi calls dont work. Can you suggest any solution to run MVC as well as CGI on IIS 5.1?

Comment: @BabyDuck No, I don't have access to IIS 5.1 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you for 100% certain, but my guess is yes you can. There is nothing special about the .NET framework required to be hosted on IIS 5--it just ISAPI's it. To IIS, .NET is simply another ISAPI filter, so it doesn't care what magic you are doing as long as you give it some text back from it's call. But again, I don't know for sure that MVC (.NET 3.5) plays nice with IIS 5.1

From a security perspective, there are all sorts of reasons not to host on IIS 5.1, but if that's not an issue (and performance isn't critical) then IIS 5 should be able to host .NET 3.5 apps.

Read about the security problems if you plan on deploying to the internet w/ IIS 5.1.